# Sapper/Svelte rollup/plugin-json giving error with stripejs

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, sapper

I'm using sapper and stripejs. After installing stripejs using the command "npm install stripe --save" and followed the npm instruction to use the package:

```
 import Stripe from 'stripe';
    const stripe = new Stripe('mystripekey');
```

I get an error during reloading. This is a screenshot because I've never seen it before and I don't know how to fix this issue at all. It needs someone from the rollup team/expert and let us know how to fix it:
[image]

I installed the plugin-json as per the instruction and it is showing in the rollup.config.js so it is not the stripe package but it seems that the rollup  has a bug or is not processing something.

Here is my rollup.config.js after installing the rollup plugin installation from [this url](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json) :

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import config from 'sapper/config/rollup.js';
import pkg from './package.json';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const dev = mode === 'development';
const legacy = !!process.env.SAPPER_LEGACY_BUILD;

const onwarn = (warning, onwarn) => (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY' && /[/\\]@sapper[/\\]/.test(warning.message)) || onwarn(warning);
const dedupe = importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/');

export default {
    client: {
        input: config.client.input(),
        output: config.client.output(),
        plugins: [
            json(),
            replace({
                'process.browser': true,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            svelte({
                dev,
                hydratable: true,
                emitCss: true
            }),
            resolve({
                browser: true,
                dedupe
            }),
            commonjs(),

            legacy && babel({
                extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte'],
                runtimeHelpers: true,
                exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**'],
                presets: [
                    ['@babel/preset-env', {
                        targets: '> 0.25%, not dead'
                    }]
                ],
                plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
                        useESModules: true
                    }]
                ]
            }),

            !dev && terser({
                module: true
            })
        ],

        onwarn,
    },

    server: {
        input: config.server.input(),
        output: config.server.output(),
        plugins: [
            replace({
                'process.browser': false,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            svelte({
                generate: 'ssr',
                dev
            }),
            resolve({
                dedupe
            }),
            commonjs()
        ],
        external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(
            require('module').builtinModules || Object.keys(process.binding('natives'))
        ),

        onwarn,
    },

    serviceworker: {
        input: config.serviceworker.input(),
        output: config.serviceworker.output(),
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            replace({
                'process.browser': true,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            commonjs(),
            !dev && terser()
        ],

        onwarn,
    }
};
```

**From  the package install instruction:**
I'm suppose to do this:

```
  **Then call rollup either via the CLI or the API.    
  With an accompanying file src/index.js, the local package.json file would 
  now be importable as seen below:**

// src/index.js
import pkg from './package.json';
console.log(`running version ${pkg.version}`);
```

But I don't have index.js file?...This is my project sapper structure:

[image]

without that last step, it seems to break the whole thing because when I reload everything, I get this in the command prompt:

[image]

and opening the browser with localhost:3000/stripe gives me a 500 error

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "http". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "http". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

How should I deal with this issue? I appreciate any help and I think this is a rollup configuration issue.

Comment: @Rich Harris We need your expertise here.

Comment: I think you have to put the rollup config in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install the `plugin-json` and use it correctly in `rollup` config, inside `plugins`

after installing make sure you have it in your `package.json`

```
...
"@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
```

and then inside `rollup.config.js`:

```
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

...

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [
        json(),  <<--------- HERE
        svelte({
...
```

Now it should work.

Comment: @V-Sambor Thank you for helping. I added everything you mentioned in your answer and now II'm getting http error. It seems we're close but now we broke the http model. I have no experience with rollup and I have no idea where is the conflict problem but I think it is rollup... Also, I added the rollup config file, and updated screenshots of all the project structure and error that I'm getting. Please review.

Comment: Hi @Marco, I think better would be if you can put your code on github into a public repository, so that people can try and help.. ;) Meanwhile Try to comment the lines with `dedupe` in resolve plugins  (both client and server) and let me know if you see any difference

Comment: @V-Sambor  Thank you. I will do that and update my question with the link to github.

Answer (score 4):

For my scenario, problem was still persisting after installation of @rollup/plugin-json and config in rollup.config.js.

I found out that rollup config has 2 sections: client and server and the problem is gone after adding json() config to plugin of both sections.

Hope can help someone.

Comment: From the code posted in the question. this was also likely the issue with the config (note no `json()` in server section)